# Understanding the branch visualization of git

Tags: git

I have 3 branches `master ==> 2 ==> 3`.

1. I first created master and submitted a file.
2. l I created branch `2`, modified the file and...
3. created branch `3`.

Why is the fork symbol in the icon of `2` and `3` and not in the blue line? It would make it easier to understand which branch is forked from which one. I know this example uses `Sourcetree` but several visualizations use the same representation. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: To the person who requested a close. Please elaborate!

Comment: I don't understand your question. You have created three branches that form a linear history. That's what I see in the graphic in your question. What exactly do you expect to see that is different?

Comment: As written in my question, I would expect a fork in the blue line and not in the icon. Just by this view, you can't see if 3 was forked from master or 2. E.g. in Perforce the revision graph makes pretty clear which file goes from where to where. I know, this is on a file basis, but still: http://media.tumblr.com/79b14569355d12569bc0068b117561a5/tumblr_inline_ms86npZuXa1qz4rgp.png

Comment: What do you mean by "a fork"? This is not a core git concept. I'll have to guess you in fact want to refer to *branches* here. The symbol means "branch", not "fork". In git world, branches don't have the same role they have in Perforce. You're trying to use a tool with the paradigm of another (not to blame you, of course, this is difficult to avoid and you're not the only one to struggle with this type of questions).

Comment: The icon means "2" and "3" are **branches**. It's visually makes more sense once you have more than 1 commit per branch, as you'll see **branches** "2" and "3" branching away from master or master branching away from 2 and 3. It's not clear what you are looking for, but I see nothing unclear with what's displayed.

Comment: Don't remember that branches are pointers pointing toward a commit. Here each branch is displayed as a label with a little branch icon inside the line of the commit it points to.

Answer (score 1):

The icon you are referring to is not used to show *a fork*. That is the icon they decided to use to indicate that is a **branch**.